# How to store wxImage into database, using C++?

Tags: c++, mysql, wxwidgets, blobstorage

I have some wxImages and I would like to store them into a [BLOB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blob.html) (Binary Large OBject) field in a MySQL database.

There are no methods in [wxImage](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wximage.html#wximageconverttobitmap) nor [wxBitmap](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxbitmap.html#wxbitmapconverttoimage) for obtaining the binary data as an array of `unsigned char` so I can load into the database.

My current workaround is to write the image to a temporary file, then load the BLOB field directly from the file.

Is there a more efficient method to load and store a wxImage object into a MySQL BLOB field?

I am using MySql C++ connector 1.05, MS Visual Studio 2008, [wxWidgets](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/) and C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wxWidgets doesn't provide any API to the data from `wxBitmap` (because it's platform-dependent) but `wxImage` uses a well-defined (and very simple) format which you can access using its `GetData()` method as mentioned above. Just notice that you may need to use `GetAlpha()` as well if your images have alpha channel.

However this is not how I'd do it because the data will be **huge** if you do it like this. While compressing it, as also suggested above, is possible, why bother doing it manually when `wxImage` already supports writing image in any of the standard image formats. Just create a `wxMemoryOutputStream` and pass it to `SaveFile()`. Then simply access the stream buffer directly using `GetOutputStreamBuffer()->GetBufferStart()` and related functions.

Comment: Last time I tried saving uncompressed, I could not create the image from the data.  When I went the temporary file route, there were no problems with the image.  The API says not to use `SetData` unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: Even although I do *not* advise doing it like this, there is still really no reason whatsoever this shouldn't work so all I can say is that there must have been some bug in your code somewhere. Unfortunately it's impossible to be more precise without any additional information.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, couldn't you use WxImage::GetData (http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wximage.html#wximagegetdata) to get the data and then ::GetHeight and ::GetWidth to know the length of the data that pointer points to? The unsigned char * that is returned by WxImage::GetData looks like it should point to the RGB data that makes up the image.

Comment: You are right. This should work. However, you may want to compress the data.

Comment: Some MySQL BLOB examples say to encode the data so it is in printable range to avoid any *dangerous* binary values.  Also, how does one create an image from the data?